# Which content management for react websites?

Tags: reactjs, express, content-management-system

I'm getting to be quite proficient at writing websites with a reactjs frontend. So far I've used a .NET Core backend and an SQL database with it, but recently I've gone a bit into switching the .NET stuff out for an ExpressJS backend.

However, for many web pages it can be helpful to have some sort of content management system for the customer to put in custom texts and stuff.

So ... what do you guys suggest I look into for content management? It would preferrably have to work with a reactjs frontend and probably an expressjs backend.

Comment: So far I've seen many people recommend GraphCMS. Perhaps that's a great way to go?

Comment: ...and if I use GraphCMS, it seems that I won't need ExpressJS or a database at all. Am I correct?